# Execute Sudo and ssh sequentially through shell script

Tags: ssh, sudo

I am trying to execute below three commands through interactive mode sequentially and it works fine. But when I use the same command through shell script, control struck after sudo, the second command ssh is not executing without user intervention.

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash webuser
ssh -i /home/webuser/gcp/gcpusercer.pem testuser5@gcpservername.org
telnet 1 3300

if [[ $1 == *"gcp"* ]]

then
    sudo su -s /bin/bash webuser

    ssh -i /home/webuser/gcp/gcpusercer.pem testuser5@gcpservername.org

    telnet 1 3300

fi
```

Comment: Why do you need the first line in a script? This line executes a shell, it doesn't make sense in a script. Also, running `sudo` inside a script Is generally not recommended - instead force running the entire script as root.

Comment: Thanks! for the responses. I used below code and executing the script as "webuser" and able to connect to the telnet host. I need to give credentials, execute some command and exit. how do i give the input to this telnet session. SSH_OUTPUT="sshout.log" printf -v cmd 'telnet %q %q' "1" "3300" ssh -t -i /home/webuser/gcp/gcpusercer.pem testuser5@gcpservername.org $cmd &> $SSH_OUTPUT

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your script.

1. Both `sudo` and `ssh` (except when running a single command over ssh) are commands that require user interaction. So they can't be "just" run in a script.
2. Commands in a script are executed **sequentially**. That means even if the commands did not require user interaction, `ssh` command would be executed **after** the shell started by `sudo` finishes, and `telnet` command would be executed **after** the ssh session finishes. That is probably not what you want. When you run these three command manually, you are running `telnet` **inside** a ssh session that is running **inside** a shell started by `sudo`. To do the same thing programatically, you need a more advanced tool than just a shell script. You could try to use [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) for example.

A very simple "skeleton" of an expect script that does what you want may look like this (of course this is NOT tested in any way):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn sudo su -s /bin/bash webuser
expect "ssword:"
send "insert_sudo_password_here\r"
expect "$ "
send "ssh -i /home/webuser/gcp/gcpusercer.pem testuser5@gcpservername.org\r"
expect "ssword:"
send "insert_ssh_password_here\r"
expect "$ "
send "telnet 1 3300\r"
interact
```

If password is not required in `sudo` and/or `ssh` commands, remove appropriate `expect`/`send` command pairs that look for the password prompt and send the actual password.

Comment: Thanks! for the responses. I used below code and executing the script as "webuser" and able to connect to the telnet host. I need to give credentials, execute some command and exit. how do i give the input to this telnet session.  SSH_OUTPUT="sshout.log"
  printf -v cmd 'telnet %q %q' "1" "3300"
  ssh -t -i /home/webuser/gcp/gcpusercer.pem testuser5@gcpservername.org $cmd &> $SSH_OUTPUT

Comment: Instead of the `interact` command in the above expect script (this gives control back to the user and resumes interactive operation), you can continue with `expect`/`send` pairs checking for prompts and entering all the input you need, complete with commands needed to exit the session.

Comment: Thanks! Raj... Is there a way I can send the below commands to the telnet host in the same ssh line and save the result to a oufile
  
  input.txt with below content
  username123
  pass321
  show tine
  exit
  
  something like this
  ssh -t -i /home/webuser/gcp/gcpusercer.pem testuser5@gcpservername.org $cmd < input.txt &> $SSH_OUTPUT

Comment: Again, to interact with **interactive** programs I recommend using tools like expect, and not overcomplicated and unclear (and thus very easy to break) shell scripts.